# Recursive XML parsing using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am working on XML data extraction using php and came across two challenging issues to deal with...I have been trying to figure this one out but couldn't.

I have category listing page in which I am extracting all the Product Ranges from my XML file based on the field "ProductRange" in my XML which may contain data like these:

*Phones;TopRatedProducts*  (means Product will belong to both Product Ranges: Phones & TopRatedProducts)

*Phones;Accessories* (means Product will belong to both Product Ranges: Phones & Accessories)

*PSP;TopRatedProducts* (means Product will belong to both Product Ranges: Phones & TopRatedProducts)

I have products in my XML that belong to two different product ranges, identified by semicolon.

**Question#1:** How can I hide the Product Range (ProductRange)that has semicolon(;) in it so that it won't appear repeatedly with other product ranges e.g Phones and TopRatedProducts etc?

Here is the PHP code that lists all the categories:

***Product Range Page Code:***

```
   <?
   $id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(3)); // $id consists of urldecoded "WebCategory"
   $list = groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/products.xml'), "WebCategory");
   foreach ( $list[$id] as $product )
   {
    $results[]=$product->ProductRange;
   } 
  ?>

   <?   
    $product_range = array_unique($results);
    foreach ($product_range as $range)
    {
      $try=mysql_real_escape_string($range);   
    ?>
    <a class="item" href="/subcategories/listings/<?=$range?>">
    <span><? print("{$range}\n\n");?></span>
    </a>
    <?}?>

   <?
   function groupBy($xml, $categoryName)
  {
   $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
   $category = array();
   foreach ( $xml as $row ) 
      {
        $attr = $row->attributes();
        if (! isset($attr->$categoryName))
        {
        trigger_error("$categoryName does not exist in XML");
          break;
         }

    $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
      }
    return $category;
   }
     ?>
```

**Note :**        This code gives me output like this:

- Phones;TopRatedProducts
- Phones;Accessories
- TopRatedProducts
- Accessories
- PSP;TopRatedProducts

But the output I want should be like this:

- Phones
- Accessories
- PSP
- TopRatedProducts

I need to separate the semicolon Product Ranges so that I could display them separately for related products.

**Question 2:**

How can list my products that belong to both ProductRanges i.e. I want to treat ProductRange="Phones;TopRatedProducts" as two separate Product Ranges to list all the products that come under "Phones", "TopRatedProducts" etc and behave like this mysql for such ProductRanges :

*"select * from products where ProductRange='Phones'";*

And

*"select * from products where ProductRange='TopRatedProducts'";*    ?

The code :

// This code list all products based on Product Range

```
    $id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(3)); // $id consists of urldecoded ProductRange
    $list = groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/products.xml'), "ProductRange");

     foreach ($list[$id] as $product ) {
     $img=getImageDirectory($product->Code); ?>
    <h3><a href="#"><?=$product->Name?></a></h3>
        <p><?=$product->WebDescription?></p>
     <img class="" src="<?=$img?>"/>

  <?}?>


      function getImageDirectory($iId) {
      $oDirectory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/var/www/Wha/images/categories/");
      $oIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($oDirectory);
       foreach($oIterator as $oFile) {
         if ($oFile->getFilename() == $iId.'.jpg') {
           return $oFile->getFilename();
          }
   }
   }

      ?>
```

Here is my XML:

Products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows> 
 <Row Code="23000" Name="HTC Wildfire S-A510E " ProductRange="Phones;TopRatedProducts"    ProductSubRange="HTC" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight."   Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
 <Row Code="34001" Name="Iphone 4" ProductRange="Phones;Accessories" ProductSubRange="Apple" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
  <Row Code="45002" Name="Samsung Galaxy S3" ProductRange="Phones;TopRatedProducts" ProductSubRange="Samsung" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
   <Row Code="10010" Name="Samsung Galaxy earphone" ProductRange="Accessories" ProductSubRange="Samsung" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
   <Row Code="10011" Name="PSP 3000" ProductRange="PSP;TopRatedProducts" ProductSubRange="Sony" WebCategory="Consoles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
    <Row Code="10012" Name="Sony Erricsson Satio" ProductRange="Phones" ProductSubRange="Sony Ericsson" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
    <Row Code="10012" Name="Sony Playstation 4" ProductRange="TopRatedProducts" ProductSubRange="Sony" WebCategory="Consoles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />

      </Rows>
```

I am not getting a clue how can I filter my results accordingly?

Comment: There is at least one place where you are closing and immediately reopening server tags.

Comment: See .. the question is to long ... make it shot and direct put your expected input and output ..eg you added `groupBy` twice ???  am sure i wore that function

Comment: @Asad i have modified the code.I hope this will make things more clear to you.bless

Comment: It has been resolved over 2 hrs ago what else do you want ?

Comment: @Baba Thanks Baba.I appreciate your help.Bless

Comment: @Baba Baba I need your kind guidance to resolve this challenging issue.Noone could resolve this .Hope you could give better solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181833/challenging-issue-xml-data-sorting-using-php

Comment: @BilalKhalid .. it looks like duplicate to me

Comment: @Baba the problem is to sort XML data accordingly in ascending order.Any idea?Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181833/challenging-issue-xml-data-sorting-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
// Display XML with ProductRange Phones
$list = groupBy(file_get_contents('1.xml'), "ProductRange", array("show" => true,"delimiter" => ";","name" => "Phones"));

// Do NOT XML with ProductRange Phones and shwo the rest
$list = groupBy(file_get_contents('1.xml'), "ProductRange", array("show" => false,"delimiter" => ";","name" => "Phones"));

// Display XML with ProductRange TopRatedProducts
$list = groupBy(file_get_contents('1.xml'), "ProductRange", array("show" => true,"delimiter" => ";","name" => "TopRatedProducts"));

// Display XML with ProductRange only TopRatedProducts
$list = groupBy(file_get_contents('1.xml'), "ProductRange", array("only" => "TopRatedProducts"));
```

Your modified function

```
function groupBy($xml, $categoryName, $options = array()) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $category = array();
    foreach ( $xml as $row ) {
        $attr = $row->attributes();
        if (! isset($attr->$categoryName)) {
            trigger_error("$categoryName does not exist in XML");
            break;
        }

        if (empty($options)) {
            $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
        } else {
            if (isset($options['only'])) {
                if ($attr->$categoryName == $options['only']) {
                    $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
                }
            } else {
                switch ($categoryName) {
                    case 'ProductRange' :
                        $name = strtolower($options['name']);
                        $parts = explode($options['delimiter'], strtolower($attr->$categoryName));
                        $condition = $options['show'] ? in_array($name, $parts) : ! in_array($name, $parts);
                        if ($condition) {
                            $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $category;
}
```