# Challenging Issue - XML Data Sorting Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have xml file that contains huge amount of Product data. I need to sort my products according to my field(ProductRange)'s data.

```
$ProductRange=urldecode($_GET['Range']);
```

**XML file data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows>
<Row Code="10026" Name="Eden 36cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta"  
ProductRange="Eden;3" ProductSubRange="EDEN 36CM ROUND PLANTER"  />
<Row Code="10031" Name="Lid only for 30l Crystal and Uni Clear" 
ProductRange="Crystal;410;Uni;3" ProductSubRange="30Ltr LID"    />
<Row Code="10088" Name="Casa Hipster Laundry Basket Silver" ProductRange="Casa;2"  
ProductSubRange="CASA HIPSTER LAUNDRY BASKET" />
<Row Code="10091" Name="Casa Hipster Laundry Basket Ice White" 
ProductRange="Casa;8;Laundry;1" ProductSubRange="CASA HIPSTER LAUNDRY BASKET"   />
<Row Code="10200" Name="Eden Grid Cover Black" ProductRange="Eden;8" 
ProductSubRange="EDEN DRAIN TIDY/GRID COVER" />
<Row Code="10249" Name="Lid only for 50L Uni Assorted" ProductRange="Uni;1" 
ProductSubRange="50Ltr MAXI BOX LID"  />
<Row Code="10259" Name="Uni 50L Box Clear" ProductRange="Uni" ProductSubRange="MAXIBOX" />
<Row Code="10269" Name="Eden 46cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta"       
ProductRange="Eden;1" ProductSubRange="EDEN 46CM ROUND PLANTER"  />
</Rows>
```

The Field "ProductRange" contains the value/order i.e ProductRange="{Range of Product};{Sorting Order of Product it should appear under ProductRange}". For example, the product with Code="10031" and ProductRange="Crystal;410;Uni;3" should appear under both Crystal with Sorting ASCENDING order 410 and Uni with sorting order 3 respectively.And ProductRange
without semicolon such as ProductRange="Uni" can appear in any order.
Please Note a ProductRange can have multiple products as indicated in XML with semicolon.

**Question:**
How can i sort my products by splitting the ProductRange field using PHP so that it could generate results like in this Ascending sorting order :

*Eden:*

```
  Code: 10269         Name: Eden 46cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta
  Code: 10026         Name: Eden 36cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta 
  Code: 10200         Name: Eden Grid Cover Black
```

*Uni:*

```
 Code=10259          Name: Uni 50L Box Clear
 Code:10249          Name: Lid only for 50L Uni Assorted 
 Code:10031          Name: Lid only for 30l Crystal and Uni Clear
```

*Crystal:*

```
  Code:10031         Name: Lid only for 30l Crystal and Uni Clear
```

*Casa:*

```
  Code:10088         Name: Casa Hipster Laundry Basket Silver
  Code="10091"       Name: Casa Hipster Laundry Basket Ice White
```

and so on.....

How can I extract data in this order? Kindly help me.

Comment: Why is `Name:Eden Grid Cover Black` not included in the Eden list ??

Comment: @Baba sorry.I couldn't mention.I have edited the required output.Hope it will make things more clear.Bless

Comment: @Baba Is this the something you cant help?

Answer (score 0):

Your previous function would do just fine all you need is minor changes

Change

```
                case 'ProductRange' :
```

To

```
                case 'ProductRange' :
                case 'Name' :
```

Or Simply remove the switch statement

Then call

```
$list = groupBy($xml, "Name", array("show" => true,"delimiter" => " ","name" => "Eden"));
print("<pre>");
foreach ( $list as $name => $value ) {
    foreach ( $value as $element ) {
        printf("Code:%s         Name: %s\n",$element['Code'],$name);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Code:10026         Name: Eden 36cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta
Code:10200         Name: Eden Grid Cover Black
Code:10269         Name: Eden 46cm Shallow Round Planter Terracotta
```

Comment: @BabaYou are real magician. Thank u so much.I cant believe this was achievable in php. Baba I wanted to sort all the products related to "Eden" in ascending order so i used "name" => "Eden".But when i run the code,it showed all the records without sorting EDEN in ascending order: See Ouput on : http://bradfordstradeday.co.uk/test.php   See Code : http://bradfordstradeday.co.uk/test.txt   See XML: http://bradfordstradeday.co.uk/test.xml .Please advise.    I appreciate you for this as i m struggling with this plz.